# Points inside Polygon (excluding boundaries)

Tags: c++, polygon

I am currently finding the co-ordinates inside a particular shape with 12 vertices.

```
          (3,7)  (5,7)
            #######
            #     #
            #  X  #
       (3,5)#     #(5,5)
 (1,5)#######  X  #######(7,5)
      #                 #
      #  X  X  X  X  X  #
      #                 #
 (1,3)#######  X  #######(7,3)
       (3,3)#     #(5,3)
            #  X  #
            #     #
            #######
          (3,1)  (5,1)
```

I would like to find out the coordinates inside the shape (marked 'X'), excluding the coordinates that make up the shape.

I've tried pnpoly by W. Randolph Franklin (http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html), but it also considers the coordinates that make up the shape as "inside the shape".

Do note that the above shape is just an example. The coordinates could be anywhere.

How can I modify the code such that it doesn't allow the inclusion of the boundaries of the shape?

```
int pnpoly(int vertx[], int verty[], int testx, int testy) {
    int nvert = 12;
    int i, j, c = 0;
    for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
        if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) && (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) ) {
            c = !c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: If that is really the shape you want to test against, it's probably easier to just do intersection with two rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shrink the shape by the border that you want to exclude, then use the existing algorithm.

BTW: Don't use `int vertx[]`, it's a dangerous lie. The equivalent obvious code is `int* vertx`, which makes it obvious that it lacks a `const`.

Comment: 'Shrinking' will only work if all edges are axis aligned, but the poster has stated that "coordinates could be anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

Since you have code to test if the point is inside a given polygon, you just need to exclude those points that are *on* the polygon. *Note: This test is only reliable if you're using integer coordinates (not floats).*

```
struct Point {
  int X;
  int Y;
};

bool PointOnLineSegment(const Point pt, const Point linePt1, const Point linePt2)
{
  return ((pt.X == linePt1.X) && (pt.Y == linePt1.Y)) ||
    ((pt.X == linePt2.X) && (pt.Y == linePt2.Y)) ||
    (((pt.X > linePt1.X) == (pt.X < linePt2.X)) &&
    ((pt.Y > linePt1.Y) == (pt.Y < linePt2.Y)) &&
    ((pt.X - linePt1.X) * (linePt2.Y - linePt1.Y) ==
      (linePt2.X - linePt1.X) * (pt.Y - linePt1.Y)));
}

bool PointOnPolygonEdge(const Point pt, Point *poly, int vertexCnt)
{
  if (vertexCnt < 2) return false;
  vertexCnt--;
  for (int i = 0; i < vertexCnt; ++i)
    if (PointOnLineSegment(pt, poly[i], poly[i+1])) 
      return true;
  if (PointOnLineSegment(pt, poly[vertexCnt], poly[0])) return true;
  return false;
}
```

**EDIT** (Dec 8, 2018):
My (old) answer above can be much improved upon ...
Reference "The Point in Polygon Problem for Arbitrary Polygons" by Hormann & Agathos
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.5498&rep=rep1&type=pdf

```
struct Point { int X; int Y; };
typedef std::vector< Point > Path;

int PointInPolygon(const Point &pt, const Path &path)
{
  //returns 0 if false, +1 if true, -1 if pt ON polygon boundary
  int result = 0;
  size_t cnt = path.size();
  if (cnt < 3) return 0;
  Point ip = path[0];
  for(size_t i = 1; i <= cnt; ++i)
  {
    Point ipNext = (i == cnt ? path[0] : path[i]);
    if (ipNext.Y == pt.Y)
    {
        if ((ipNext.X == pt.X) || (ip.Y == pt.Y && 
          ((ipNext.X > pt.X) == (ip.X < pt.X)))) return -1;
    }
    if ((ip.Y < pt.Y) != (ipNext.Y < pt.Y))
    {
      if (ip.X >= pt.X)
      {
        if (ipNext.X > pt.X) result = 1 - result;
        else
        {
          int d = (ip.X - pt.X) * (ipNext.Y - pt.Y) - 
            (ipNext.X - pt.X) * (ip.Y - pt.Y);
          if (!d) return -1;
          if ((d > 0) == (ipNext.Y > ip.Y)) result = 1 - result;
        }
      } else
      {
        if (ipNext.X > pt.X)
        {
          int d = (ip.X - pt.X) * (ipNext.Y - pt.Y) - 
            (ipNext.X - pt.X) * (ip.Y - pt.Y);
          if (!d) return -1;
          if ((d > 0) == (ipNext.Y > ip.Y)) result = 1 - result;
        }
      }
    }
    ip = ipNext;
  } 
  return result;
}
```